# make row in table visible and invisible

Tags: javascript, html

```
if (a == 1) {
  document.getElementById("visible2").style.visibility = "collapse";
} else {
  document.getElementById("visible2").style.visibility = "none";
}
```

[this is my table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ExbBY.png)

I want to make single rows of a table visible or invisible with the state of the variable `a` (variable `a` is a placeholder for plc variables).

Comment: use `display="none"` and `display=""` instead `visibility`

Comment: `visibility="hidden"`

Comment: What is the question? Please read the docs on correct values for `visibility` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/visibility

Comment: it works for me with display and visibility but only with text and not the row of the table